# Sql query to find high of individual days

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

```
date           value
2015-06-27     8088.15
2015-06-27     8083.25
2015-06-27     8068.25
2015-06-24     8246.45
2015-06-24     8343.55
2015-06-24     8232.35
2015-06-24     8564.65
2015-06-23     8354.75
2015-06-23     8455.25
2015-06-23     8451.45
2015-06-22     8343.55
2015-06-22     8345.75
2015-06-21     8023.75
2015-06-21     8029.85
2015-06-20     8023.95
```

I need to find individual max(value) for latest 3 dates. I need output like this.

```
date           max(value)
2015-06-27       8088.15
2015-06-24       8564.65
2015-06-23       8455.25
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT MAX( value ) 
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE
IN (SELECT * 
FROM (    
SELECT DISTINCT DATE
FROM table_name
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 3
) AS t
)
```

But this is actually giving overall max(value) for latest 3 dates. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
SELECT date, MAX( value ) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY DATE desc
LIMIT 3
```

Explanation: It will select the `grouped date` along with `maximum VALUE` which is `ORDERED BY date` and will return 3 rows due to `LIMIT 3`

Comment: Thanks Nikhil it worked :)

Comment: You are welcome @ChiyaanSuraj. Do accept if useful :)

Comment: You answered very quickly :). I can accept the answer only after 8 mins it seems.

Comment: Didn't we do this one already?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the query to work, your desired max value should be grouped according to days so therefore you should add `GROUP BY` clause
in your query to limit only the result of the max value based on the grouped date.

```
SELECT date, MAX(value) FROM table_name
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY DATE desc
LIMIT 3;
```